# Opinión sobre esquema MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola :happy: Hace algún tiempo comencé a aprender acerca del diseño de base de datos SQL y actualmente estoy trabajando en el diseño de una base de datos para una aplicación de Quizzes. Entre los requerimientos surge la necesidad de que los propios usuarios realicen sus propios Quizz para ser compartidos con otros usuarios dentro de una futura plataforma web.

Mi esquema es el siguiente:

[image: Esquema]

En donde tengo una tabla compuesta llamada "**QuizzesAnswered**" la cual me permitirá verificar que usuarios han contestado determinados **Quizzes**. Y cree una relación de uno a muchos para permitir a los usuarios realizar sus propios Quizzes. He escuchado que en algunas situaciones se debe evitar el uso de relaciones en ciclo, desconozco si en este caso aplica y si en algún futuro me pueda generar problemas. ¿Existe una mejor manera de diseñar dichas relaciones?

Comment: Para empezar yo haria una tabla questions_quiz donde pondria el id de quiz y de la pregunta, de esa forma si tenes que volver a reutilizar la pregunta solo la cargas una sola vez en pregunta y en questions_quiz agregas el id del nuevo quiz y el de la pregunta reciclandola y no duplicas datos en la tabla question

Comment: @Juan Gracias por tu sugerencia :D se aprecia mucho